# c# - Adding Attachment To Discord Webhook Message

Tags: c#, file, discord, embed, attachment

I m trying to add img, .dat file etc. To Discord WebHook Message. ( Local Files ).

Here is my code;

Content Part:

```
string url = "webhook"
string mesaj "example";

 NameValueCollection message = new NameValueCollection()  {
                    { "username", "Beko BOT" },
                    { "avatar_url", "https://i.ibb.co/qrcrHP4/B-Kare.png"},
                    { "content", mesaj }
                };

                Http.Post(url, message);
```

Sending Part:

```
public class Http
{
    public static byte[] Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
        byte[] numArray;
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            numArray = webClient.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
        return numArray;
    }

}
```

Thanks For Helping !

Answer (score 2):

WebHook messages don't have attachments, see [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook).

However, there is a `file` field where you can put your local file, the same way as you do it for messages with attachments or embeds. If you need to send a few files at once, you can include embeds with files in them.

Sadly, I cannot provide the exact code to do that as I'm coding in a different language. But I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125408/is-there-a-way-to-insert-pictures-gifs-to-embeds-from-local-storage) that seems relevant as it concerns sending local files, and a comment to it points to a [documentation article](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html#usage-with-local-images) describing how to send an embed with a local file. The author of that question found it helpful.